# Can't cast custom UITableViewCell Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]I have a custom class for a UITABLEVIEWCELL. Trying to make a custom table view cell. I was hoping some one could explain what was going on with my code thats resulting in this error?

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit

class familyUnit_TblCll_iPhone: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var familyName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var familyPhoto: UIImage!

    @IBOutlet var familyUnitGuardianCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var familyUnitChildCount: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var familyUnitGuardianIcon: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet var familyUnitChildIcon: UIImage!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code

        //Set Defaults for Cell Elements.
        self.familyName.text = ""
        self.familyUnitChildCount.text = String(0)
        self.familyUnitChildCount.text = String(0)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode--don't abuse tags.  Post your code, not screenshots of your code.  Post your error, not screenshots of your error.  Double check your storyboard to make sure the cell with this ID has its class set to this strangely named class of yours...

Comment: You need to post your familyUnit... class so we can help you

Comment: You haven't set the custom class of your prototype cell in your storyboard, so it is defaulting to a `UITableViewCell` class.

Comment: @lcaro I have added the code you asked for thanks. Let me know if there is more I should post.

Comment: It isn't anything to do with the code - You haven't set the custom cell class in your storyboard

Comment: @Paulw11 I actually have set the class on the storyboard. Thats is what is confusing me.

Comment: You haven't set it correctly since the exception is quite clear - you have an instance of a `UITableViewCell` and so you can't force a downcast to your custom class.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just included an image of where I set the class. Is this in the correct place on the storyboard?

Comment: I can't tell from that screen shot.  That is where you set a custom class, but I can't see what object you have set that on - is it associated with the correct tableview cell (reuse identifier) in the correct table view in the correct scene?  Also you should re-read the Swift Programming Guide on naming classes - By convention a class name should start with an uppercase letter in camel case (e.g. FamilyUnitTableViewCell)

Comment: It looks right - Have you checked the re-use identifier.  What happens if you click the arrow next to the class name?  Does it open the correct class?  Try removing the custom class and re-adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go to the Attributes Inspector (in the storyboard it's just next to the Identity Inspector, like on your screenshot) and for the Identifier attribute add the same string as in you code line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("familyUnit_TblCll_iPhone") as! familyUnit_TblCll_iPhone
```

so in the storyboard, for the identifier add "familyUnit_TblCll_iPhone" and it should work.

I really do not suggest you to use such strings or either class names! Take a look at this nice "Swift Code Guide": https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming